# Is there an implicit type casting when using Functional Interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, casting, java-17, functional-interface

I wrote the following Java code and expected it to not compile but it did and also executed counterintuitively. I am using Java 17.

`TestFunctionExecutor.java`

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TestFunctionExecutor{
    void execute();
}
```

`TestClass.java`

```java
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        test.wrapper(test::sampleFunction);
    }
    
    public void sampleFunction() {
        System.out.println("Inside sampleFunction");
    }

    public void wrapper(TestFunctionExecutor method) {
        System.out.println("Before method execution");
        method.execute();
        System.out.println("After method execution");
    }
}
```

Output -

```
Before method execution
Inside sampleFunction
After method execution
```

---

I thought since `wrapper` expects an argument of type `TestFunctionExecutor` and I am passing one of type `TestClass` the compilation should fail. I used a debugger and looks like `method` is a `TestClass$$Lambda$1...` at runtime. This confuses me and I have a few questions -

1. What is the type of `test::SampleFunction`? Is it not `TestClass` or something like `TestClass$$sampleFunction...`? I am unable to deduce this with a debugger.
2. Why were there no errors here? Looks like the types somehow became compatible, how?
3. How does `execute` know what code to execute?
4. Is this good code? My aim is to wrap a function so that some code runs before and after it.

Thanks!

Comment: "since wrapper expects an argument of type TestFunctionExecutor and I am passing one of type TestClass" you are NOT passing instance of TestClass, but instance of lambda (of type TestClass$$sampleFunction... which is *subtype* of `TestFunctionExecutor`) which is *using* `TestClass test`. Anyway the `foo:::bar` syntax is called *method reference* but to properly grasp it you should start with lambdas. Consider reading http://www.lambdafaq.org/ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Thanks for the resources @Pshemo, I'll go through them. One quick question - You said "`TestClass$$sampleFunction...` is a subtype of `TestFunctionExecutor`". How?

Comment: Because of *type inference* compiler knows that argument for method `public void wrapper(TestFunctionExecutor method)` must be of type `TestFunctionExecutor` (including its subtypes). So when compiler creates class like `TestClass$$Lambda$1...` to be implementation of lambda or method reference it must ensure that such class is subtype of TestFunctionExecutor which means it `... implements TestFunctionExecutor` (since that is what `wrapper` method expects as argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, lambda expressions are just a sugar syntax for something called [Anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which are basically classes created on the spot with a name created by the JVM.

Your code can be equally written in 4 ways (from more concise to less concise) :

```java
test.wrapper(test::sampleFunction);

test.wrapper(() -> test.sampleFunction());

test.wrapper(() ->  {
   test.sampleFunction();
});

test.wrapper(new TestFunctionExecutor() {
    public void execute() {
       test.sampleFunction();
    }
});
```

When you use a lambda expression, you actually create a new instance of an anonymous class that implements the functional interface. And the method of this implementation contains the run you want to run.

As for the last question, it might be correct code, but this is a very broad topic that depends.